# Django queryset, __in not working on dynamic list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a weird problem with using __in in queryset (using with Django 1.4 and SQLite).

I have a model with fields:

```
city=somecity

activities=[u'one',u'two',u'three']

activity=one
```

now

```
city = request.user.account.city
activities = request.user.account.activities
queryset = profile_model._default_manager.filter(city__exact=city,activity__in=activities)
```

doesn't work, but if I change it to

```
city = request.user.account.city
activities = request.user.account.activities
queryset = profile_model._default_manager.filter(city__exact=city,activity__in=[u'one',u'three'])
```

then it's ok.
I get activities that same way as I get city, so it should't be a problem.
I'm using something similar in other queryset

```
activities__contains=activity
```

but in this queryset I'm searching for "activities", and if I do it the same in this queryset it's returning error, because there is no such a field (in this case "one").

I was trying

```
activity__in=list(activities)
```

but it's also not working.

If I put it to template as:

```
{% if activity in activities %} 
yes 
{% else %} 
no
{% endif %}
```

It's working without a problem.

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the ouput of `print activities` in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming activities is a relationship with another model, I belive it should be

```
activities = request.user.account.activities.all()
```

...as `request.user.account.activities` is a manager and `request.user.account.activities.all()` returns all the activities. I believe the template tag "assumes" the all() in this case. Django templates do many sophisticated things to help rapid development.

Please see also here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward for more information.

Comment: Nope, activities is a user profile field (list).
Adding .all() is giving an error "'unicode' object has no attribute 'all'".